# YII without the possibility to refresh/resend form on reload

Tags: php, forms, yii

So I'm currently trying to convert my website to YII framework, but for now I'm mostly playing around and learning how it works.

A little thing is bugging me, I would like that my forms would not have the reload/resend box popup when refreshing the page. On my old website I was using the `header("Location: current page")` to reload the page and get ride of that box, then using sessions variables I was able to handle errors and stuff.

How could I achieve so that my Yii forms have the same functions either with php header redirect or maybe javascript ?

I'm new to yii so I'm not yet fully understanding how it all works but I got the basics I think.

Answer (score 5):

Yii Controllers comes with some redirect functions.

inside any controller action

```
// to refresh current action
$this->refresh();
// or
Yii::app()->controller->refresh();
```

to redirect to another action ...

```
$this->redirect('controller/action', array('queryparam1' => 'val1', ...) );
// or
Yii::app()->controller->redirect('controller/action', array('queryparam1' => 'val1', ...) );

// or
 Yii::app()->request->redirect('controller/action', array('queryparam1' => 'val1', ...) );
```

if you want to store some information between page redirects, you can use Yii Flash (it uses session inside).

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/172/an-easy-way-to-display-a-success-page-using-flash-messages/

Comment: But my problem is when the form is submitted and there is an error and it doesn't get sent and errors are displayed. Is there any way to not have the get the resubmit message ?